# adb shell input text not working for lock screen in Le2

Tags: android, adb

I have been trying sending key events to my Le2 phone through `adb shell input` lately and have been partly successful.
When I try using adb shell input text xxxx when device is unlocked, it works(say on some notes app or sms text).
However, on trying entering the pin on lock screen `input text xxxx` yields nothing :(

I have tried entering the pin on a lock screen for a Stock Android phone running Oreo using `adb shell input text` and it works fine as expected.

What could possibly be different that it doesn't works for my Le2?
What could be done to get it working on my Le2 running on Marshmallow and using EUI.

Any thoughts or suggestion are welcome.

Comment: input text will work if the text box is on focus. Otherwise not. Its like you are typing on keyboard without cursor. May be this is the reason in Le2.?

Comment: I do not find any reason for the text box to not to be in focus for Le2, unless there's some weird implementation of the EUI. When I unlock manually, I do not need to bring the text box in focus. Why should it be for adb?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a Huwaei Mate SE, did you figure out a work around? Works fine on a Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: Unfortunately not :( Nicolas. I stopped working on it.

Comment: same problem here for HuaWei DIG-AL00, can NOT fix it.